# Postgres select distinct with different order by without using a subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-11

There's lots of answers on how to do this that involve a subquery but the subquery for us leaves the performance lacking. It appears that all the results from the subquery are determined before the outer query executes.

We have a database structure where a **Product** holds a **Variant** which holds an **Access** (aka store) and scaling this up seems particularly annoying on postgres, as distinct needs to match the order by which is not what we (or anyone shopping online) would want. The database is not even that large at 28M rows of Access' and 15,000 Products.  Without the subquery and proper indexes the performance is very good, in the 10's of milliseconds. With the subquery it ends up in the thousands of milliseconds (this is on an M.2 PCIe SSD).

In this example I'm attempting to:

1. Only return 1 row per product
2. Satisfy the where condition (location, could be other things)
3. Make sure we show in stock products first
4. Make sure we show the most expensive products first

The index matches this exactly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      DISTINCT ON ("products_displayproduct"."id") "products_displayproduct"."id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."date_created", 
      "products_displayproduct"."date_updated", 
      "products_displayproduct"."name", 
      "products_displayproduct"."sub_title", 
      "products_displayproduct"."tags", 
      "products_displayproduct"."has_multiple_variants", 
      "products_displayproduct"."placement_id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."hidden_placement_category_id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."hidden_placement_super_category_id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."brand_id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."poster_image_id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."rating", 
      "products_displayproduct"."reviews", 
      "products_displayproduct"."is_toppick", 
      "products_displayproduct"."last_amalgamation", 
      "products_displayproduct"."search_index", 
      "products_displayproductaccess"."is_instock" as "subquery_instock", 
      "products_displayproductaccess"."price" as "subquery_price" 
    FROM 
      "products_displayproduct" 
      INNER JOIN "products_displayproductvariant" ON (
        "products_displayproduct"."id" = "products_displayproductvariant"."product_id"
      ) 
      INNER JOIN "products_displayproductaccess" ON (
        "products_displayproductvariant"."id" = "products_displayproductaccess"."product_variant_id"
      ) 
    WHERE 
      (
        "products_displayproductaccess"."location_id" IN (
          608, 65, 610, 69, 999, 72, 92, 79, 81, 84, 
          1045, 89, 601, 954, 603, 1276, 605, 607
        )
      ) 
    ORDER BY 
      "products_displayproduct"."id" ASC NULLS LAST, 
      "products_displayproductaccess"."is_instock" DESC NULLS LAST, 
      "products_displayproductaccess"."price" DESC NULLS LAST
  ) as subquery 
ORDER BY 
  "subquery"."subquery_instock" DESC, 
  "subquery"."subquery_price" DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: You've explained a lot about problems and the environment.  But I don't see any sample data or desired results and am rather lost on what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Please consider [instructions for Postgres performance questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info). How many rows in `products_displayproductvariant`? Etc. I see multiple problems in the query, but this is at its core: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/18300/3684. The solution isn't trivial, and heavily depends on the complete situation. Please explain what the given query is supposed to achieve exactly. And is `LIMIT 10` just for testing or in the productive version, too?

Comment: This was solved by not using a sub query and specifying the other two field in the distinct as well, with products_displayproduct.id being simply the last entry.

Comment: Unrelated, but: all those double quotes are useless.

Answer (score 0):

I've always found that using `DISTINCT` bogs my queries down immensely. Try using `GROUP BY` instead. Either in the sub query:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      "products_displayproduct"."id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."date_created", 
      "products_displayproduct"."date_updated", 
      "products_displayproduct"."name", 
      "products_displayproduct"."sub_title", 
      "products_displayproduct"."tags", 
      "products_displayproduct"."has_multiple_variants", 
      "products_displayproduct"."placement_id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."hidden_placement_category_id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."hidden_placement_super_category_id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."brand_id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."poster_image_id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."rating", 
      "products_displayproduct"."reviews", 
      "products_displayproduct"."is_toppick", 
      "products_displayproduct"."last_amalgamation", 
      "products_displayproduct"."search_index", 
      "products_displayproductaccess"."is_instock" as "subquery_instock", 
      "products_displayproductaccess"."price" as "subquery_price" 
    FROM 
      "products_displayproduct" 
      INNER JOIN "products_displayproductvariant" ON (
        "products_displayproduct"."id" = "products_displayproductvariant"."product_id"
      ) 
      INNER JOIN "products_displayproductaccess" ON (
        "products_displayproductvariant"."id" = "products_displayproductaccess"."product_variant_id"
      ) 
    WHERE 
      (
        "products_displayproductaccess"."location_id" IN (
          608, 65, 610, 69, 999, 72, 92, 79, 81, 84, 
          1045, 89, 601, 954, 603, 1276, 605, 607
        )
      ) 
    GROUP BY 
      "products_displayproduct"."id"
    ORDER BY 
      "products_displayproduct"."id" ASC NULLS LAST, 
      "products_displayproductaccess"."is_instock" DESC NULLS LAST, 
      "products_displayproductaccess"."price" DESC NULLS LAST
  ) as subquery 
ORDER BY 
  "subquery"."subquery_instock" DESC, 
  "subquery"."subquery_price" DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Or in your main query:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      "products_displayproduct"."id" as "subquery_id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."date_created", 
      "products_displayproduct"."date_updated", 
      "products_displayproduct"."name", 
      "products_displayproduct"."sub_title", 
      "products_displayproduct"."tags", 
      "products_displayproduct"."has_multiple_variants", 
      "products_displayproduct"."placement_id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."hidden_placement_category_id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."hidden_placement_super_category_id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."brand_id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."poster_image_id", 
      "products_displayproduct"."rating", 
      "products_displayproduct"."reviews", 
      "products_displayproduct"."is_toppick", 
      "products_displayproduct"."last_amalgamation", 
      "products_displayproduct"."search_index", 
      "products_displayproductaccess"."is_instock" as "subquery_instock", 
      "products_displayproductaccess"."price" as "subquery_price" 
    FROM 
      "products_displayproduct" 
      INNER JOIN "products_displayproductvariant" ON (
        "products_displayproduct"."id" = "products_displayproductvariant"."product_id"
      ) 
      INNER JOIN "products_displayproductaccess" ON (
        "products_displayproductvariant"."id" = "products_displayproductaccess"."product_variant_id"
      ) 
    WHERE 
      (
        "products_displayproductaccess"."location_id" IN (
          608, 65, 610, 69, 999, 72, 92, 79, 81, 84, 
          1045, 89, 601, 954, 603, 1276, 605, 607
        )
      ) 
    ORDER BY 
      "products_displayproduct"."id" ASC NULLS LAST, 
      "products_displayproductaccess"."is_instock" DESC NULLS LAST, 
      "products_displayproductaccess"."price" DESC NULLS LAST
  ) as subquery 
GROUP BY 
  "subquery"."subquery_id"
ORDER BY 
  "subquery"."subquery_instock" DESC, 
  "subquery"."subquery_price" DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: 2nd) ERROR:  column "subquery.date_created" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function